# Play framework 2.2.0 doesn't generate getter/setter automatically

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.2

While tacking Play framework, I've found really annoying situation that I had to spend much time to point out where is root of evil!

To simplify the situation let's consider the code below :

In `controllers.Application.java` :

```
return ok(views.html.method1.render(Person.find.all());
```

In `method1.scala.html` :

```
@(people : List[Person])
...
@for(person <- people) {
     @person.name
     @person.pet.getName()
     @person.pet.name
}
```

In `Person.java` :

```
@Id
public Long id;
@ManyToOne
public Pet name;
...
```

The problem is when I manually set getName() method inside of `Pet` class. The value is returned. 
But when I let to be generated automatically by Play framework, it doesn't return any value!

Certainly Play framework has generated getters for `person` which I can access by `person.name`.

It's not supposed to be generated automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaEbean states that getters and setters are generated at runtime (for *plain old Java libraries* that require them) and won't be visible at compile time:

> Play has been designed to generate getter/setter automatically, to
>   ensure compatibility with libraries that expect them to be available
>   at runtime (ORM, Databinder, JSON Binder, etc). If Play detects any
>   user-written getter/setter in the Model, it will not generate
>   getter/setter in order to avoid any conflict.
>
> Caveats:
>
> (1) Because Ebean class enhancement occurs after compilation, do not
>   expect Ebean-generated getter/setters to be available at compilation
>   time. If you’d prefer to code with them directly, either add the
>   getter/setters explicitly yourself, or ensure that your model classes
>   are compiled before the remainder of your project, eg. by putting them
>   in a separate subproject.
>
> (2) Enhancement of direct Ebean field access (enabling lazy loading)
>   is only applied to Java classes, not to Scala. Thus, direct field
>   access from Scala source files (including standard Play templates)
>   does not invoke lazy loading, often resulting in empty (unpopulated)
>   entity fields. To ensure the fields get populated, either (a) manually
>   create getter/setters and call them instead, or (b) ensure the entity
>   is fully populated before accessing the fields.

Therefore the getter isn't visible in your template.
If you need lazy loading (see **2)**) I suggest you let your getters and setters generate by your IDE.
If you don't need lazy loading, just access the fields, they are `public` anyway.

BTW: a reference in class `Person` to class `Pet` named `name` sounds like an awkward data model, no offense.